# Download file via SFTP one line CLI command with password containing special character (no ssh key)

Tags: bash, sftp, synology, lftp

I've got a Synology that needs to download and archive a file from SFTP server.

I used to use WGET when FTP protocol was being used, but the file owner changed the protocol to SFTP.

```
wget -m ftp://username:password@host/* -P /volume1/local/folder
```

So now I cannot use WGET and need to use something else.

From my reading I can use **sftp** or **lftp** commands.

The one liners for those do not work because password has @ character in it.

I have tried:

```
sftp --password="password" "username"@"host":/* /volume1/local/folder
```

But, sftp is throwing:

```
unknown option -- -
```

I also cannot install **sshpass**, because it will stop working as soon as I get update on Synology machine.

Is there a way to do this? Should I be doing this through a bash script?

PS: I cannot install ssh key on the SFTP server. Its owned by another entity and they will not do this for me.

UPDATE:

```
lftp -u 'username','password@' 'host' -p 22 "ls; bye"
```

This seems to be working. Trying to get the download to work.

The **ls** command is showing this output for some reason:

```
`ls' at 0 [FEAT negotiation...]
```

UPDATE:
A bit of progress but not enough:

```
lftp -u 'username','password@' 'host' -p 22 -e "set ftp:use-feat false; set ssl:verify-certificate no; get FILE.ZIP; bye"
```

This seems to be connecting, but gets stuck on TLS negotiation:

```
`FILE.ZIP' at 0 [TLS negotiation...]
```

Comment: Try replacing the `@` for `%40`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I tried: lftp sftp://username:password%40@host -e "ls; bye" and it just kept saying "`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]" - so I assume it failed to login :(

Comment: I also tried: lftp -u 'username','password' 'host' -e "ls; bye" this seems to be working but it denies access. I checked username and password and they are correct. Do I need to specify SFTP:// in the hostname?

Comment: No, I don't think you need.

Comment: I added port with -p command, it seems to be connecting, but ls command is not outputting anything.

Comment: `pftp -p 22` cannot work. It imo makes lftp try to use FTP protocol on SFTP port. You need to tell lftp to use the SFTP, what you do by the `sftp://` prefix – Like this: `lftp -u 'username','password@' sftp://host "ls; bye"`

Comment: @KalvinKlien Now I'm not so sure about specifying the protocol, I'm diving into the manual but I can't find a reference to it.

Comment: Use the option `-d` (debugging) as in `lftp -d ...`, it will show the process, maybe some information there will be helpful